# Storing a reference to a reference in Python?

Tags: python, reference

Using Python, is there any way to store a reference to a reference, so that I can change what that reference refers to in another context? For example, suppose I have the following class:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
      self.standalone = 3
      self.lst = [4, 5, 6]
```

I would like to create something analogous to the following:

```
class Reassigner:
   def __init__(self, target):
      self.target = target
   def reassign(self, value):
      # not sure what to do here, but reassigns the reference given by target to value
```

Such that the following code

```
f = Foo()
rStandalone = Reassigner(f.standalone) # presumably this syntax might change
rIndex = Reassigner(f.lst[1])
rStandalone.reassign(7)
rIndex.reassign(9)
```

Would result in `f.standalone` equal to `7` and `f.lst` equal to `[4, 9, 6]`.

Essentially, this would be an analogue to a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: I think the whole point of references is that you should not be able to just do that.

Comment: How do you intend to use this?

Comment: If you want C++, you know where to find it...

Comment: @FogleBird The plan was in deferred assignment of named references. A bunch of objects are loaded from xml files, which may make references to other objects by name. If you reference a name that doesn't yet exist, you get a placeholder object, and get stuck into a table of things with dangling references. If you later encounter the definition of that name, you would go through all the appropriate entries in the table of dangling references, and reassign the placeholder values to the newly-created objects. There are solutions with layers of indirection, but I was hoping for something direct.

Comment: @professional_yet_not_trackable That is **exactly** (modulo XML) what I was doing when I encountered this problem and came up with the solution that now is my answer. Supports my theory that there are extremely few use cases for this.

Comment: I usually do a two-pass load for that scenario. First, load all objects (and use a dict to map ID => object) and then do another pass to establish the links between the objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, it's not possible. At all. The closest equivalent is storing a reference to the object whose member/item you want to reassign, plus the attribute name/index/key, and then use `setattr`/`setitem`. However, this yields quite different syntax, and you have to differentiate between the two:

```
class AttributeReassigner:
    def __init__(self, obj, attr):
        # use your imagination
    def reassign(self, val):
        setattr(self.obj, self.attr, val)

class ItemReassigner:
    def __init__(self, obj, key):
        # use your imagination
    def reassign(self, val):
        self.obj[self.key] = val

f = Foo()
rStandalone = AttributeReassigner(f, 'standalone')
rIndex = ItemReassigner(f.lst, 1)
rStandalone.reassign(7)
rIndex.reassign(9)
```

I've actually used something very similar, but the valid use cases are few and far between.
For globals/module members, you can use either the module object or `globals()`, depending on whether you're inside the module or outside of it. There is no equivalent for local variables at all -- the result of `locals()` cannot be used to *change* locals reliably, it's only useful for *inspecting*.

I've actually used something very similar, but the valid use cases are few and far between.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You can't.
Complicated answer: You can use lambdas. Sort of.

```
class Reassigner:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.reassign = target

f = Foo()
rIndex = Reassigner(lambda value: f.lst.__setitem__(1, value))
rStandalone = Reassigner(lambda value: setattr(f, 'strandalone', value))
rF = Reassigner(lambda value: locals().__setitem__('f', value)
```

Comment: Why `__setitem__` and not just direct item access with `[]`?

Comment: Duh, because that woudn't be a lambda

Comment: As Eric seems to have realized :), `f.lst[1]=value` is not an expression, but `f.lst.__setitem__(1, value)` is.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to defer assignments; you could use `functools.partial` (or just `lambda`):

```
from functools import partial

set_standalone = partial(setattr, f, "standalone")
set_item = partial(f.lst.__setitem__, 1)
set_standalone(7)
set_item(9)
```

If `reassign` is the only operation; you don't need a new class.
Functions are first-class citizens in Python: you can assign them to a variable, store in a list, pass as arguments, etc.

Comment: `operator.setitem` makes the item case symmetric to the attribute case, and looks better.

Comment: @delnan: I thought about it but I wanted to demonstrate that `partial` also works on methods (not only functions) and there are also special methods in Python. Otherwise `operator.setitem` might be preferable because it postpones `__setitem__` lookup (exceptions are at the caller site).

Answer (score 0):

This would work for the contents of container objects. If you don't mind adding one level of indirection to your variables (which you'd need in the C pointer-to-pointer case anyway), you could:

```
class Container(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, target):
        self.standalone = Container(3)
        self.lst = [Container(4), Container(5), Container(6)]
```

And you wouldn't really need the reassigner object at all.

```
Class Reassigner(object):

    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target
    def reassign(self, value):
        self.target.val = value
```